# SPO Search from external DB

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, people-search, external-data

The scenario is this (in SharePoint Online):
 
I am trying to implement a search box, in our Intranet Page, that is connected to an external database. This is just a small DB with people's names, phone nr., office location, etc. Kind of like Corporate Phone-book.

Since the structure is already there, because it was used in the old html/php based Intranet Page, I would like to just add the Search box in our SharePoint Intranet, and connect it to this structure so that it can display result from there.

Another important factor: the result/s should be displayed in a pop-up window.
I have started with a "HTML Form Web Part". Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

Since every part of this is "custom" I would not use SPO Search. You could create an Azure SQL DB with the data and then use JavaScript and REST to send and receive the queries. This can be done from any web page, not just SharePoint online pages as SharePoint would not have anything to do with the solution.

Comment: I understand what you mean; but at the moment I am looking more for a way of connecting a search box (not sharepoint search, but a html implemented code for exemple) to an existing database and script. As a comparison: iFraming a seach from another place.

Comment: Do you mean you want to have the results show on your SPO Search Results page? You can do that by executing your code from using the "k" query string parameter.

Comment: I was actually considering the following: create a SPO List with the fields from SQL, then open it with Access and grab the data from SQL, to populate the list. But my "Open with Access" button is grey'd out, so I'm try'n to solve that one right now.

Comment: @John, can you explain a bit more about what you are trying to do? Are you trying to replicate a Table as a List in SPO?

Comment: Yes, I have a SQL database called "employees"; there are all the contact infos like: name, email, phone, building, office, etc. This was connected until now in the old intranet page to a search box. We are planning on launching a new Sharepoint based intranet page. This quick people search functionality is very important, since it is very used by people in the company. Therefor I am trying to find a way of connecting this database with a search field that i can put on the landing page of our intranet.

Comment: Why not add that information to the User Profile for each user and then use the Out of the Box People Search functionality? It is quite powerful and includes refiners. That is generally how you search for people in SP a SPO.

Comment: Because we have people working in the factory, that do not have an AD Account. But need to be found through this search. That is way this separate database was initially created.

Comment: Makes sense. I would add just create a Azure SQL database and then an app that searches it. You could add a web part to the page that uses the k query string operator for a seamless experience.